# Best way to generate url via Page.GetRouteUrl in a helper class?

Tags: asp.net, routes

I have just added routing in a new asp.net 4 web forms application, and have got my route table set up ok and page requests are working fine.

What I now want to do is use the Page.GetRouteUrl method whenever I need to generate one of my seo friendly Url's. I started to implement this across various pages then thought it might cut down on code a bit if I had a method in one of my own helper classes, that constructs this url (using the Page.GetRouteUrl method) as I might have several parameters that need to be specified against the Page.GetRouteUrl method each time.

However, within my helper class, it doesn't know what 'Page' is. I was thinking I could pass in 'Page' from the page that wants a routed url to be generated, but in some cases I want to construct one of these Url's in another class which doesn't know what 'Page' is, and in that scenario wouldn't be able to pass it in as a param (and therefore wouldn't be able to use the Page.GetRouteUrl within my helper class).

What is the normal approach when wanting to use Page.GetRouteUrl within classes that don't have an instance of the Page object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass Page as a constructor parameter, or this is actually the page reference:

```
var page = HttpContext.Current.Handler as Page;
```

You can cast it to the page type.  Depending on the type of requests you are making, it may not always be page (say from a web service call, etc.).

HTH.

Comment: Aha, so simple when you know how! :) Brilliant, works a treat. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Ah, just one other scenario I noticed - I have an .ashx handler file that dynamically generates my google sitemap for the website. As the request to generate the Url is coming from a handler file, the above approach doesn't seem to work. Is there any way around this do you know, or will I not be able to use Page.GetRouteUrl in this scenario?

Comment: Looks like your best bet is to try the RouteCollection.GetVirtualPath method; this says its virtually the same as Page.GetRouteUrl http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.getrouteurl.aspx.  Looking at reflector, that's exactly right... so you'd have to see what you can use to get that to work...  Those scenarios is one of the things I was mentioning in my later statement; it can get tricky.  Good luck.

Comment: Thanks a lot Brian, I'll have a go with that and see what I can do. Cheers.

Comment: UPDATE: I ended up finding a solution to this secondary issue, within the following thread: http://forums.asp.net/p/1322760/2718242.aspx

Comment: The above answer does not work with web services. In my opinion, the better solution is: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5947150/131165